Install tensorflow\tfjs-node on Windows 11
I've got a lot of problem installing TFJS
My situation:

Python v3.11.9 (from vscode terminal)
NodeJS v20.14.0 (from vscode terminal)
Windows 11
Visual Studio Community installed

What i've done:

Started a new NodeJS project with npm init y (from vscode terminal on the project folder)
I've run this: npm install --save-dev electron (always vs code terminal)
Then I've run this: npm install --save-exact @tensorflow/tfjs-node

With this output:
PS C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test-tensor> npm install --save-exact @tensorflow/tfjs-node                
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm warn deprecated npmlog@6.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@3.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated gauge@4.0.4: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated electron-rebuild@3.2.9: Please use @electron/rebuild moving forward.  There is no API change, just a package name change

added 269 packages, and audited 270 packages in 4m

41 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

I've made this simple main.js file:
// main.js

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')


function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})


But i get this on run of my app:
Uncaught Error Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test-tensor\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v8\tfjs_binding.node
    at Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1454:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test-tensor\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:72:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\test-tensor\main.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)


I've already tried multiple times to delete node_modules, reinstall them, rebuild with electron, change python versions, change electron versions....NOTHING WORKED!
At least this is the first time i managed to install TFJS without errors..i think.
